# "I know that that that school that is famous because of its rules." — Can this sentence work?

Tags: relative-clauses, doubled-words

This is the sentence:

> I know that that that school that is famous because of its rules.

I think the first *that* is a relative pronoun, the second also and the third is a demonstrative pronoun, the fourth *that* is a relative pronoun again. The problem is that I cannot add punctuation, I was hoping to add a comma after the first that but he says this is not allowed or that it is not needed.

Comment: That sentence is not correct, even with punctuation. The best that I can make of it is *I know that, that, that school, that is famous, because of its rules* — but it's still wrong and ugly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I thought that if I could add a comma after the first 'that',it would break it into two different clauses..would this explain it?

Comment: There would still be too many *thats*.

Comment: You *could* get away with three "thats" in a row with something like this: "I know that, that that school be famous because of its rules, its rules must be written down."

Comment: @JefSahol: The second *that* introducing a final clause, as in *in order that*? All right, but that only works because you have added another finite verb.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.Can anyone break it down for me..am I right is calling the first one and the third one  relative clauses..or is the sentence just wrong?

Comment: Did you mean "I know that that that that school is famous for is its rules"? I think that that sentence is (marginally) grammatical. I can't parse your version at all.

Comment: @Cerberus That is correct.

Comment: Someone should open a "That School" where we can all learn how to use the word "That".  Then I can say "I know that that "That School" is awesome.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I give up! I can parse [buffalo x 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo), and (just about) [had x 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher) (which cheats a bit with punctuation). But how do you make sense of **that x 4**?

Comment: I'm happy enough with *"I believe that that that is possible is real"* (using the middle *that* as an alternative to *which*). I think given the right delivery and context, you could come out with *that* without even raising any eyebrows (or pricking any ears, perhaps)

Comment: @barry: Are you perhaps trying to represent a spoken form which is effectively two separate sentences with a chunk in the middle omitted? *"I know that! [I know] that that school is blah blah"*

Comment: With regard to the third "that" in the example sentence: That "that" that that "that" user uses is one too many. The fourth one is problematic as well.

Answer (score 4):

I can only make this strange sentence fragment work by punctuating it (and adding to it) in this way. Please forgive the silly adjective (blue), but the OP's sentence needs an extra clause at the end of it.

> Amelia: That school that is famous because of its rules is blue.
>
> Reginald, irritated: I *know* that -- that that school, that is famous
>   because of its rules, is blue.

Comment: Is your example really correct? Shouldn't the third "that" (the relative pronoun in the sentence marked by commas) be a *"which"* instead?

Comment: @Paola, you may be right, but I was working with the words that the OP gave...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is an extra *that* and possibly a word out of order?  Did you mean something like?

> I know that that school is that famous because of its rules.

or for an extra that

> I know that that school is that famous because of that rule.

The only sentence construction that I am aware of that allows for the use of the same word three times in a row is along the following lines:

> The time that she had had, had been good.

but the comma is almost cheating.

Comment: "The only sentence construction that I am aware of that allows for the use of the same word three times in a row is along the following lines"... Aw, come on!  You can do better than that!  [*Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)...

Answer (score 2):

For a different angle: maybe it's a school that teaches [a certain mode system of northern India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_%28music%29), i.e. *thāt*, and perhaps its name, styled in lowercase to be hip, is just **thāt**. So, reformatted:

I know that that *thāt* school **thāt** is famous because of its rules.

This is grammatical, if a bit obscure, to my ear.

Comment: I like the thinking outside of the box. Mirrors: "I know that that jazz school jazz is famous because it breaks all the rules."

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't work.  It's incomprehensible.

It may conform to the "rules" of English grammar, but when a competent native speaker reads that sentence all he sees is word salad.  Therefore, the sentence has failed as an act of communication.

On the other hand, it has succeeded as a trigger for an interesting discussion about English grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is fine. For example:

**A**: "Do you like *that* school or *that* school?" (**A** points to each one.)

**B**: "I like *that* that school." (Points to the one he likes.)

No punctuation is needed. Emphasis need not be indicated in writing, even when it significantly aids understanding. Of course, it's very confusing without context.

While I don't think anyone would actually do it, they can continue demonstrating each other's relations to build in more and more "that"s. For example, **A** could reply, "Why do you like *that* that school more than *that* that school? What does *that* that that school have that *that* that that school doesn't?"

Comment: Hmmm-  I did not follow that at all.  I would think B would respond with "I like *that* school (B points to his preferred school).  I can't make any sense of your second *that*.

Comment: There are two schools, both of which have been related by **A** as "that school" (normally you'd use *this* and *that* for two things, but if there are three, you have to repeat). To indicate which "that school" **B** means, he uses "that" as a designator, he doesn't want *this* that school, but *that* that school.

Comment: I like your way of thinking, and repetition like this may occur in phrases like *is it a gay party, or a gay gay party?* ; however, it doesn't sound natural or acceptable to me with *that* as in the example. I believe anyone would just say *I like that school*.

Comment: It could work in a sentence like this, where *that* has a special meaning: "I don't like this magazine. I don't want to be *that girl*, you know what I mean? — But if you had to choose, <points at magazine> would you rather be this *that girl* or that *that girl*?". However, this only works when *that + word* has a special meaning, like here. There is some kind of irony involved. I don't see a *that* with a special meaning in the example, nor the right kind of irony.

Comment: this is something called [Contrastive focus reduplication](http://www.iranianlinguistics.org/papers/salad-salad.pdf) and should in theory work, but I think it's just going too far.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use these in written English:

> - I know that; that that school is famous for its rules.
> - I know that - that that school is famous for its rules.
> - I know that: that that school is famous for its rules.

And mainly spoken (or casual writing):

> I know that. That that school is famous for its rules.

For a single, flowing sentence, you can change "I know that that that school that is famous because of its rules" to:

> - I know that that school is famous for its rules.
> - I know a/ the school that is famous for its rules.

Answer (score 0):

After staring at the sentence a while I can't see a good way to parse the original sentence.

Actually, the sentence works if you add another "is".

```
Q: "Hey Joe, did you know that that, um, building over there is famous. You know what for?"

A: "Yeah, I know that, that that school, that is, is famous because of its rules."
```

I think there is a dialect, maybe U.S. Southern, that shortens ", that is," to just "that".

This would give you something like:

```
Q: "Hey Jud, d'you know dit that, er, buildin' over der is famous. You know what fer?"

A: "Yeah, I know dat, dat, dat school dat, is famous 'cause of its rules."
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence:

> I know that that school that is famous because of its rules is expensive.

The first *that* is a complementizer, the second is a demonstrative, and the third is a relative pronoun.

[image]

Now imagine you had a nice grammatical sentence like:

> Thomas knows that the student that that school that is famous because of its rules expelled died.

You might think that you could front *the student* in the process of getting a question:

> *Who does Thomas know that that that school that is famous because of its rules expelled died?

But it's ungrammatical, and generally it's notoriously hard to extract the subject of a complement clause to form a question, e.g.

> I said that all crows are black.
>   *What did I say that all are black?

So no, three consecutive *that*'s does not seem possible as far as I can tell (but see the comment below for an example).

Comment: Of course you can have three "that"s, although this sentence doesn't cut it. From Google books: *"The thing now proposed by Aristotle, though apparently very paradoxical, is to show that that which is about to stand still is the same with that which is moved."* Now, just change the "which"s to "that"s. It's still grammatical, just much more confusing.