# Is it correct to use a double “that” in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, doubled-words

Is it correct to use a double “that” in a sentence? For example, I saw the following sentence in a book, and wondered whether it is correct:

> If I do nothing else in Wallace, I want to teach my girls **that that** they can accomplish anything boys can do if they work hard and dedicate themselves to achieving goals.

Comment: Related and probably duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3418 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2459 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8743 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/69218 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21381 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/77895 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/74236 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/108402 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26028 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/37827

Comment: Although there are circumstances in which _that that_ is an appropriate construction (as discussed in the duplicates nominated), in the sentence you quote it is NOT.

Comment: By now the question has gained the status of GR.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an erroneous word duplication. There is nothing wrong with the "that that" construction, it's just not appropriate here.

For example, you could say:

> Girls can accomplish anything boys can if they work hard and dedicate themselves to achieving goals. If I do nothing else in Wallace, I want to teach my girls that that is the truth.

Comment: Before attempting to answer, it is better to check if a question has been dealt with in earlier posts.